# Ulimit for managed server and other java processes

Tags: weblogic, aix, managed, ulimit

Nn a `AIX` interface, `ulimit` is defined across two stages,

- One under `etc/security`
  -One under `$WL_HOME/common/bin/commEnv.sh`

Need to understand, the java objects coming spawning from managed servers uses which `ulimit` ?

Answer (score 0):

The last one applied.

That is, the one in $WL_HOME/common/bin/commEnv.sh

just modify the start scripts before the java virtual machine is launched to "spit" the ulimit value set.

Comment: So to be on same page - When a managed server is started, the value of ulimit is picked from commEnv.sh. If this is yes, then the java objects spawning from the managed servers will use this ulimit value.

Comment: @OP: Well, I don't know what this WL_HOME is, or what 'managed servers' you have; but if you want to be sure, set the *hard-limit* in /etc/security/login.cfg and the *soft-limit* in the server's startup-script.